# How to get mime type in Cordova getPicture

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm trying to get the mime type of selected video or image from the photo library. I can specify the encoding format of the picture but no videos. So, when I pick a video, or picture, I don't have the extension on the success function, I have a path like this: `content:://media/external/images/media/58`.

Then, how can I get the mime type of both sources (videos and images) using JavaScript and Cordova?

**Code**:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(drawImage, errorFunction, {
     quality: 50,
     mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
     destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
     encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
     sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});


var drawImage = function(image) {
    if (typeof image !== "undefined") {
            $("#uploadMedia").append("<img src='" + image + "' width='200' height='200'>");
    }
};
```